# ui datepicker before 100 with calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have an input with a datepicker. It works properly, but when I insert a date before 01/01/100 it shows me 19xx.

For example, if I insert 01/01/0001 the calendar shows me 01/01/1901

[image]

I have read that I have to use yearRange in my script, but it doesn't work for me :(

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $("#fromDatePickerEnabled_input").datepicker({
            yearRange: '1:9999'
        });
    });
</script>
```

How can I make that it shows me the year right?

Comment: What do you want it to do?

Comment: @Archer I want when I write a year before 100 it show me the year right. Currently, when I write a <100 year it shows me 19xx (xx is the year I wrote) in the calendar.

Comment: So you want it to show 2001 when you enter 01?  What about when you enter 99? What about 50 or 20 or 70?  Please think about what you are trying to do and explain it properly and fully.

Comment: @Archer No, that's what I have. I want when I enter 01 it shows me year 01. Currently, when I enter 01 it shows me 1901.

Comment: You want it to show you a 2 figure year number?

Comment: @Archer No, I just want when I write 0001 it shows me year 0001

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[It's already reported / discussed bug in the jQuery forums](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-datepicker-entered-invalid-date-is-resolved-to-another-date), since 2016, and unfortunately there aren't any fixes yet ...

**In short**: Looks like jQuery Datepicker doesn't work correctly with dates which years are less than 1000.

I tried passing different options to Datepicker (as `changeYear`, `shortYearCutoff`, `yearRange`), but no one fixes the problem. Even enabling `changeYear: true` and manually selecting the year, doesn't result in a correct Date.

**It's an option** to switch to [bootstrap-datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which doesn't have such problems with lower years.

Here you can play with it: [bootstrap-datepicker playground](https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, you confirmed my fears T_T